# How can I force Thunderbird to use my preferred text color and to ignore the text color specified in incoming messages?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, thunderbird

I use a dark theme in Ubuntu. Everything is fine in Thunderbird except for the messages that arrive where a font color is specified ( I assume Outlook forces a color to be specified). Those messages of course use the font color specified in the incoming message. This is a problem for my dark theme as the font color specified is typically a dark blue (difficult) or black (invisible against the theme's black background). How can I force Thunderbird to use my preferred text color and to ignore the text color specified in incoming messages?

Comment: Put it into [plain-text-only mode](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Plain_text_e-mail_(Thunderbird\))

Comment: I would want it for HTML emails.

Comment: [Plain-text-only mode](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Plain_text_e-mail_(Thunderbird)) (fixed link)

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem. I fixed it by choosing View->Message Body as->Simple HTML. It's the best I can do.
Just read carefully the right section on the [link provided](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Plain_text_e-mail_%28Thunderbird%29#Displaying_messages) by Oliver Salzburg on the comments.